# Docusign HMAC hash not matching

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi, hmac

I`m trying to authenticate the DocuSign request in my WebHook using HMAC but not matter what I do the generated does not match any of the incoming values.

I`m using the same key and the same code as the one in the DocuSign documentation so I guess the only thing that is different is the extraction of the request body. Did anyone manage to get this work in C# ? How did extract the request body from the request ?

My code:

```
GenerateHash(key, GetRequestBodyByteArray())

    private static byte[] GetRequestBodyByteArray()
    {

        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Copy the request stream to the memory stream.
            var stream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.CopyTo(buffer);

            // Rewind the memory stream.
            buffer.Position = 0L;
            
            return buffer.ToArray();
        }
    }



        private string GenerateHash(string connectKey, byte[] requestBody)
    {
        var keyAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(connectKey);
        var hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyAsBytes);
        var hashAsBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(requestBody);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashAsBytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/validate) Step2 C# example. Also you can simplify your StreamReader. Very simplified version will look something like this, **signature** is your **X-DocuSign-Signature-1** from the header

```
        Task<string> body;
        var signature = Request.Headers["x-docusign-signature-1"];
        string secret = "your secret";

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        var result = Hmac.ComputeHash(secret,body.Result.ToString()).Equals(signature);
```